# Adding comments for a method in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How can I add documentation comments for JavaScript methods in Visual Studio Code? Thanks for any advise!

Comment: You will find lot of examples in web to do that. Can you pls explain what did you do so far?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about any particular VSCode version from which onwards it started but I use it in VSCode directly without any extension like this:

Just type /** above the function and press Enter:

[image]

it will automatically populate the Comment structure with JSDoc Tags based on your function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension for adding jsdocs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/stevencl.addDocComments).

Comment: I'm not sure if that is meant to be an insult, but I'll assume you meant intellisense. Intellisense is supported but maybe not in the way you are imagining it.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I made a mistake. Yes, I meant intellisense. I want to get prompts after I add documentation in Visual Studio Code. But it seems that the prompts are not supported.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. That is a good idea for an extension or a feature request. Please feel free to open a feature request on the [Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues)